# Property [comment] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to get data from a column from table comment through the story table via the slug column. I've managed to do it with authors but I think I must be missing something or forgetting something because it is no longer working. I get this error

> Exception in Collection.php line 1498: Property [comment] does not exist on this collection instance.

My controller function

```
public function slug($slug){
    $menus_child = Menu::where('menu_id', 0)->with('menusP')->get();
    $stories = Story::where('slug', $slug)->get();

    $slug = $slug;

    // I used this to get the author's email going through the slug from
    // story table
    $story = Story::with('author')->where('slug', $slug)->first();
    $name = $story->author->first()->email;

    // I would like to get the name in the comment table by going through
    // the slug from the story table
    $comment = Story::with('comment')->where('slug', $slug)->get();
    $test = $comment->comment->first()->name;

    return view('open::public.single-story', compact('menus_child', 'stories', 'slug'));
}
```

my Comment.php

```
namespace App\Modules\Authors\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = array('name', 'comment');

    protected $guarded = array('id');

    protected $table = 'comments';

    //Validation rules
    public static $rules = array(
        'name' => '',
        'comment' => ''
    );

    public function story(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Modules\Authors\Models\Story', 'comment_story', 'comment_id', 'story_id');
    }
}
```

my Story.php

```
class Story extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = array('title', 'content', 'type', 'slug');

    protected $guarded = array('id');

    protected $table = 'story';

    //Validation rules
    public static $rules = array(
        'title' => '',
        'content' => '',
        'type' => ''
    );

    public function slug($title){
        $this->attributes['title'] = $title;
        $this->attributes['slug'] = Str::slug($title);
    }

    public function author(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Modules\Authors\Models\Author', 'author_story', 'story_id', 'author_id');
    }

    public function comment(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Modules\Authors\Models\Comment', 'comment_story', 'story_id', 'comment_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Are your relationships correct? They're all set to `belongsToMany()`. I'd expect a Story to have one Author (`belongsTo()`) and many Comments (`hasMany()`), and conversely a Comment to have one Story (`belongsTo()`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some help from dparoli I managed to do it. I can't believe it to me so long to figure it out.

I changed

```
$comment = Story::with('comment')->where('slug', $slug)->get();
$test = $comment->comment->first()->name;
```

to

```
$comment = Story::with('comment')->where('slug', $slug)->first();
$test = $comment->comment->toArray();
```

and I added test to

```
return view('open::public.single-story', compact('menus_child', 'stories', 'slug', 'test'));
```

and then added

```
@foreach($test as $t)
  <h1>{!! $t['name'] !!}</h1>
  <p>{!! $t['comment'] !!}
@endforeach
```

to my view

Comment: Nice to know you found a satisfing solution by yourself, good job.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this:

```
//here you get a collection of stories 
$comment = Story::with('comment')->where('slug', $slug)->get();
```

To this:

```
//here you get a single story
$comment = Story::with('comment')->where('slug', $slug)->first();
```

Comment: Then how do I display all the comments that goes with that story?

Comment: Maybe @dparoli is right. Try his solution first, then check if `comment` returns an object or collection. Like `dd($comment)`. The reason being that `first()` is linked to the Story, not the comments.

Comment: The `$comment = Story::with('comment')->where('slug', $slug)->first();` displays the story. But I can't seem to get all the comments to show

Comment: IMHo youre code has not only an issue, try to solve one by one as and watch what you get on every single step like @EddyTheDove suggests, ist easier.

Answer (score 0):

I give you a different approach to try

```
$comments = Comment::with(['story' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('slug', '=', $slug);
}])->get();
```

Give this a go if it works for what you are trying to accomplish.